# Where can I find DirectShow debug information (i.e.Quartz.pdb)?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, directshow, debug-symbols, pdb-files

The dump file I am reviewing includes references to *Microsoft*'s *DirectShow* library (i.e. `Quartz.dll`).  Unfortunately I don't have the corresponding programmer database file (i.e. `Quartz.pdb`)... so I can't see what functions are being called.

Do you know where I can download `Quartz.pdb`?

**ADDITIONAL CONTEXT**

- `Quartz.dll` version 6.6.9600.1815
- The following did not bear fruit:

  - searching the various SDKs on our build machine for `Quartz.pdb`
  - installing [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit)
  - configurating *Visual Studio 2013* to request `*.PDB` files from *Microsoft*'s symbol server

Answer (score 1):

There is no special resource for these PDBs (quartz.dll is a part of Windows core) - they are available from well known [Microsoft public symbol server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552208) at https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.

See also: [where can get quartz.pdb file?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/04060099-aca4-4800-b2c3-4e1612848edf/where-can-get-quartzpdb-file?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment#a5358cf8-48e1-43f7-9ea2-86b6f42a8cfe) on MSDN Forums.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Roman. When I configure Visual Studio to use Microsoft's public symbol server, all the `*.dll` files in the call stack are resolved *except* Quartz.dll. Doesn't *Visual Studio* use https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols when I select `Tools` => `Options` => `Debuggin` => `Symbols` => `Microsoft Symbol Servers` ?

Comment: Configuration is just regular. It might so happen they don't have this specific version of DLL (including due to some intermittent problem). I checked my debug symbols cache and I see a number of quartz.dll/pdb versions. I am absolutely sure I used to download the pdbs before in a very straightforward way. And I don't think you can get the PDBs elsewhere.

Comment: Also I just checked that for a version currently in use on my dev system, quartz.pdb (version 10.x.x.x though) is available from public symbol server. I remember I had a problem with specific version, and in the same time PDB for another bitness (32 vs. 64) was available.